# Logging using the free monad

Tags: haskell, logging, functional-programming, free-monad

This question is related to [this article](http://degoes.net/articles/modern-fp)

The idea is to define a DSL for manipulating files in the cloud, and define a
composition of interpreters that take care of the different aspects, such as
communication with the REST interface and logging.

To make this more concrete, assume we have the following data structure that
defines the terms of the DSL.

```
data CloudFilesF a
= SaveFile Path Bytes a
| ListFiles Path ([Path] -> a)
deriving Functor
```

We define functions to build CloudFiles programs as follows:

```
saveFile :: Path -> Bytes -> Free CloudFilesF ()
saveFile path bytes = liftF $ SaveFile path bytes ()

listFiles :: Path -> Free CloudFilesF [Path]
listFiles path = liftF $ ListFiles path id
```

Then the idea is to interpret this in terms of two other DSL's:

```
data RestF a = Get Path (Bytes -> a)
         | Put Path Bytes (Bytes -> a)
         deriving Functor

data Level = Debug | Info | Warning | Error deriving Show
data LogF a = Log Level String a deriving Functor
```

I managed to define a natural transformation from the CloudFiles DSL to the
REST DSL with the following type:

```
interpretCloudWithRest :: CloudFilesF a -> Free RestF a
```

Then given a program of the form:

```
sampleCloudFilesProgram :: Free CloudFilesF ()
sampleCloudFilesProgram = do
  saveFile "/myfolder/pepino" "verde"
  saveFile "/myfolder/tomate" "rojo"
  _ <- listFiles "/myfolder"
  return ()
```

It is possible to interpret the program using REST calls as follows:

```
runSampleCloudProgram =
  interpretRest $ foldFree interpretCloudWithRest sampleCloudFilesProgram
```

The problem comes when trying to define an interpretation of the DSL using
logging. In the article I referred above, the author defines an interpreter
with type:

```
logCloudFilesI :: forall a. CloudFilesF a -> Free LogF ()
```

and we define an interpreter for `Free LogF a` having type:

```
interpretLog :: Free LogF a -> IO ()
```

The problem is that this interpreter cannot be used in combination with
`foldFree` as I did above. So the question is how to interpret a program in
`Free CloudFilesF a` using the function `logCloudfilesI` and `interpretLog`
defined above? Basically, I'm looking to construct a function with type:

```
interpretDSLWithLog :: Free ClouldFilesF a -> IO ()
```

I can do this with the REST DSL, but I cannot do it usng `logCloudfilesI`.

What is the approach taken when using free monads in these situations? Note
that the problem seems to be the fact that for the logging case, there is no
meaningful value we can supply to the function in `ListFiles` to build the
continuation of the program. In a [second article](http://degoes.net/articles/modern-fp-part-2)
 the author uses `Halt`, however,
this does not work in my [current implementation](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/blob/master/free-monads/src/CloudFiles.hs).

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my remark which was missing some bit of the story. It seems you are trying to interpret a `Free CloudFilesF` thing entirely in terms of `LogF`, but this will never work if you don't also somehow feed `[Path]` into the process, since most of a `Free CloudFilesF a` is stuck behind functions `[Path] -> a`, so you can't get to it - unless you feed it `[]`

Comment: For example you can write `debugI :: CloudFilesF r -> Free LogF r` as
`debugI (SaveFile path bytes r) = log Debug (path ++ bytes) >> return r`;
`debugI (ListFiles path next) = log Debug path >> return (next [])`

Comment: I think that's part of the problem (and also part of my question): how to add logging in a context of free monads. It seems interpreting `Free CloudFilesF` in terms of `Free LogF` is not the right approach, but I wonder what's the place of `LogF` in the whole process.

Comment: What you mention in your second comment is what I did at some point, but returning an empty list did not seem right (at least from an architectural point of view), although it did the job.

Comment: When he did it, he interpreted `CloudFilesF` into `Sum LogF RestF` or whatever - i.e. he stuck a bit of logging onto his rest interpreter, so he could write something like `logRest :: CloudFilesF r -> Free (Sum LogF RestF) r` as `logRest cf = hoistFree InL (logCloudFilesI cf) *> hoistFree InR (interpretCloudWithRest cf)` (here using `Data.Functor.Sum` for his coproducts)

Comment: That way, I don't lose the all-important connectedness of a `Free CloudFilesF` item - it is preserved by `interpretCloudWithRest` which knows how to 'get' files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logging is a classic use-case for the decorator pattern.

The trick is to interpret the program in a context which has access to both the logging effects and some base effect. The instructions in such a monad would *either* be logging instructions *or* instructions from the base functor. Here's the *functor coproduct*, which is basically "`Either` for functors".

```
data (f :+: g) a = L (f a) | R (g a) deriving Functor
```

We need to be able to inject programs from a base free monad into the free monad of a coproduct functor.

```
liftL :: (Functor f, Functor g) => Free f a -> Free (f :+: g) a
liftL = hoistFree L
liftR :: (Functor f, Functor g) => Free g a -> Free (f :+: g) a
liftR = hoistFree R
```

Now we have enough structure to write the logging interpreter as a decorator around some other interpreter. `decorateLog` interleaves logging instructions with instructions from an arbitrary free monad, delegating interpretation to a function `CloudFiles f a -> Free f a`.

```
-- given log :: Level -> String -> Free LogF ()

decorateLog :: Functor f => (CloudFilesF a -> Free f a) -> CloudFilesF a -> Free (LogF :+: f) a
decorateLog interp inst@(SaveFile _ _ _) = do
    liftL $ log Info "Saving"
    x <- liftR $ interp inst
    liftL $ log Info "Saved"
    return x
decorateLog interp inst@(ListFiles _ _) = do
    liftL $ log Info "Listing files"
    x <- liftR $ interp inst
    liftL $ log Info "Listed files"
    return x
```

So `decorateLog interpretCloudWithRest :: CloudFilesF a -> Free (LogF :+: RestF) a` is an interpreter which spits out a program whose instruction set consists of instructions from `LogF` and `RestF`.

Now all we need to do is write an interpreter `(LogF :+: RestF) a -> IO a`, which we'll build out of `interpLogIO :: LogF a -> IO a` and `interpRestIO :: RestF a -> IO a`.

```
elim :: (f a -> b) -> (g a -> b) -> (f :+: g) a -> b
elim l r (L x) = l x
elim l r (R y) = r y

interpLogRestIO :: (LogF :+: RestF) a -> IO a
interpLogRestIO = elim interpLogIO interpRestIO
```

So `foldFree interpLogRestIO :: Free (LogF :+: RestF) a -> IO a` will run the output of `decorateLog interpretCloudWithRest` in the `IO` monad. The whole compiler is written as `foldFree interpLogRestIO . foldFree (decorateLog interpretCloudWithRest) :: Free CloudFilesF a -> IO a`.

In his article, de Goes goes (ha ha) a step further and builds this coproduct infrastructure using [prisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html). This makes it simpler to abstract over the instruction set.

The USP of the [`extensible-effects`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible-effects) library is that it automates all this wrangling with functor coproducts for you. If you're set on pursuing the free monad route (personally, I'm not as smitten with it as de Goes is) then I'd recommend using `extensible-effects` rather than rolling your own effect system.

Comment: This is what de Goes does in the relevant section of the post, though, with `loggingCloudFilesI`

Comment: Yep, more or less. The above is basically a recap of the part of the article that OP seems not to understand. The main difference is that de Goes doesn't build his logger as a decorator.

Comment: `decorateLog` might be clearer  as something like  `addLogging :: CloudFilesF a -> Free (Sum LogF CloudFilesF) a` then other manipulations would use standard combinators like `retract` `hoistFree` etc.

Comment: Indeed, I was thrown off by the fact that de Goes uses `logCloudFilesI :: forall a. CloudFilesF a -> Free LogF ()`. In his second post he uses `Halt` as well, but none of these constructs can be put together in the same way as the REST interpreter.

Comment: @Michael, any reason for preferring `Sum` over `Coproduct`?

Comment: @DamianNadales `Data.Functor.Sum` is in `base` (previously it was in `transformers` which is a boot package that comes with ghc) so it's the standard module for forming the coproduct of two functors.

Comment: @DamianNadales in fact you don't need coproducts for this kind of manipulation, if you use `FreeT`, which gives you room to act on the different functors separately. Here is a version using the `streaming` library (where the general `Stream` type is the same as `FreeT` )http://lpaste.net/281553

Comment: I walked through this for my own sake, but without the use of co-product (sum), instead I rolled my own: http://therning.org/magnus/posts/2016-06-18-free--take-2.html

Comment: @Magnus right, here is a version that dispenses with coproducts http://lpaste.net/281889 You can toggle back and forth between the coproduct view and the other (more natural?) view of decoration with [separate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming.html#v:separate) and unseparate. Note that these compose so `separate . separate` disaggregates a `Sum (Sum f g) h)` so that f can be acted on separately, and so on.